# Im building a clicker game and localstorage is returning with nothing instead of saved data

Tags: javascript

So I'm building a clicker game on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mmccall0813/pen/jdwjdj) and I ran into a problem while coding my save/load functions. It seems as if my save function may not me working, but I'm not sure why.
Here are the functions:

```
function savegame(){
  localStorage.clicks = Number(document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML); 
  localStorage.cps = document.getElementById('cps').innerHTML; 
                localStorage.clickPower = 
Number(document.getElementById('clickpower').innerHTML); 
                localStorage.onecpow = Number(document.getElementById('1clickpowe').innerHTML); 
                localStorage.onecps = Number(document.getElementById('1cps').innerHTML); 
                localStorage.fivecps = Number(document.getElementById('5cps').innerHTML); 
                localStorage.fivecpow = Number(document.getElementById('5clickpower').innerHTML); 
                localStorage.tencps = document.getElementById('10cps').innerHTML;}
function loadgame(){document.getElementById('1clickpower').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("onecpow");
       document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("clicks");
                document.getElementById('cps').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('cps'); 
                document.getElementById('clickpower').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('clickpower');
                document.getElementById('5clickpower').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('fivecpow'); 
                document.getElementById('5cps').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('fivecps'); 
                document.getElementById('1cps').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('onecps'); 
                document.getElementById('10cps').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('tencps');}
```

I forgot to clarify what I'm expecting the code to do. What this should do is save the players progress and upgrades, instead upon loading the saved data the players data is not loaded and returns many blank spaces where saved data should have been loaded.

Comment: https://codepen.io/awesom3/pen/Hlfma

Comment: Your game looks like it's working perfectly to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing `localStorage.onecpow = "someValue"` try

```
storage.setItem(onecpow, "someValue");
```

You can check the [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) docs here for more info

Comment: But `localStorage['variable'] = value` should do the same, there is no reason to work different

Comment: One _arguably_ good reason is to not change the `localStorage` definition. If you do `localStorage['variable'] = 'something'`, you're adding a new attribute to it, which is not what you want to do. To save something in it, there's an API provided just for that

Comment: I know, but I mean that it should not cause an error, shouldn't it? I have been using localStorage in both ways and never had an issue

Comment: No of course. The way you write it is correct too, and it will not cause any errors. It's more of a _preferences_ style I think. I say when they give an offical API to do stuff, why not use it like they say in the docs

Answer (score 2):

You are using 'localStorage' wrong. Have a look at this:

```
// writing to localStorage
localStorage.setItem('myId', value);

// reading from localStorage
var whatever = localStorage.getItem('myId');

// remove an item from localStorage
localStorage.removeItem('myId');
```

EDIT:

The problem is that you're mixing up 2 different approaches. You have to decide which one to use. Either the object-driven or the key-driven.

My example above is the key-driven approach. You should also be able to use the object-driven approach like this:

```
// writing to localStorage
localStorage.myObject = value;

// reading from localStorage
var whatever = localStorage.myObject;
```

Choose your style, but don't mix them. ;o)

Comment: After using the code I still get the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, though it's kind of strange how it works.

I added capital letters to the `localStorage` attributes and used `localStorage.setItem` and `localStorage.getItem`. Don't know why it works but it does.